# mysql select timestamps between a and b returning all or 0 timestamps

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Tried this

```
select * from table where timestamp_field between 1330560000 and 1336170420
```

and this

```
select * from table where timestamp_field >=1330560000 and timestamp_field<=1336170420
```

both returning empty result set.

But this

```
select * from table where timestamp_field >= 1330560000
```

returns all the rows

To make things more absurd

```
select * from table where timestamp_field <= 1336170420
```

returns empty result set.

Of course, there exists timestamp values before, between and after 1336170420=4.may 2012. and 1330560000=1.march 2012.

Timestamp values are ok, at least phpmyadmin shows correct (human-readable) date-time values.
I created timestamps by parsing strings, with

```
UPDATE table SET timestamp_field = STR_TO_DATE(timestamp_string, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Guess I'm missing something, but can't find what!?

Comment: are you storing your timestamp as an int or a varchar?

Comment: try changing the type to int using the structure tab in phpmyadmin unless youre relying on mysql to generate the current timestamp somewhere you don't really need to specify timestamp as a datatype

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL expects [date literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html), not integer ones:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  DATE(timestamp_field) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-05-04'
```

To use integers (assuming that they are seconds since the UNIX epoch), first convert them using MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  timestamp_field BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1330560000)
                           AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1336170420)
```

Or else use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to convert your column to its UNIX representation:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_field) BETWEEN 1330560000 AND 1336170420
```

Comment: you're welcome for a beer and kebab if near belgrade ;) this saved me a night

Answer (score 0):

why not convert the timestamps from_unixtime(timestamp/1000) as dateTime while using your sql code?  have you tried that?

Comment: don't quite get it. example would be usefull. i really tried understanding how mysql handles date and time, but no success :(

Comment: ahh eggyal beat me that's where i was getting to.